# How to access success and error of a Promise<string>?

Tags: f#, fable-f#

I have an API that returns `Promise<string>`:

```
let response: Fable.Core.JS.Promise<string> = ApiClient.fetchGet "https://google.com"
```

I figured out how to process a success value within it:

```
response
    |> Promise.iter (fun response ->
        printf $"{response}"
    )
```

But how could I process not only the success string, but an error string as well?

Comment: Promise.catch maybe?  https://fable.io/fable-promise/documentation/pipeline.html

Comment: Thanks, I liked `eitherEnd` better https://fable.io/fable-promise/reference/Fable.Promise/global-promise.html#either_end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found multiple ways: using `Result` type, `eitherEnd`, `map`/`catchEnd`:

```ml
response
    |> Promise.result
    |> Promise.iter (fun res ->
        match res with
        | Ok success -> printfn $"success: {success}"
        | Error err -> printfn $"error: {err}"
    )
```

```ml
response
    |> Promise.eitherEnd
        (fun success -> printfn $"success: {success}")
        (fun err -> printfn $"error: {err}")
```

```ml
response
    |> Promise.map (fun success ->
        printfn $"success: {success}"
    )
    |> Promise.catchEnd (fun err ->
        printfn $"error: {err}"
    )
```